# how to convert a string of numbers to a list and square up ** and get it printed out back as string

Tags: python, string, list, tuples, square

Given a string of the form "3,9,13,4,42". It is necessary to convert it into a list and calculate its square for each element. Then join the squares of those elements back into a string and print it in the console.
input

input:
string = "3,9,13,4,42"

output:
string= "9,81,169,16,1764"

Managed to get it squared up, tried converting it to list fist, but when checked type at the end, always somehow getting it as tuple.
Ty for help.

Comment: To help you, we need to see your code.

Comment: What have you tired so far ?

Comment: may be you missed the last step : `",".join(tuple(map(lambda x: str(int(x)**2), "3,9,13,4,42".split(","))))`

Comment: `','.join(map(lambda x: str(int(x)**2), s.split(',')))` ?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this answers your question.

```py
# input
str_numbers = "3,9,13,4,42"

# string to list
str_number_list = str_numbers.split(",")

# list of strings to list of ints
number_list = [int(x) for x in str_number_list]

# square all numbers
squared_numbers = [x ** 2 for x in number_list]

# squared numbers back to a list of strings
str_squared_numbers = [str(x) for x in squared_numbers]

# joing the list items into one string
result = ",".join(str_squared_numbers)

# print it out
print(f"Input: {str_numbers}")
print(f"Output: {result}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
// First Approach

string = "3,9,13,4,42"
array = string.split(',')
array = map(lambda x: str(int(x)**2),array)
result = ','.join(list(array))
print(result) // "9,81,169,16,1764"

// Second Approach
string = "3,9,13,4,42"
result = ','.join([str(int(x)**2) for x in string.split(',')])
print(result) // '9,81,169,16,1764'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do with `split` + `join`,

```
In [1]: ','.join(map(lambda x: str(int(x)**2), s.split(',')))
Out[1]: '9,81,169,16,1764'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have so many ways to solve the problem. I'll show you a few by degree of complexity of understanding. Each way has a different computational complexity, but for such a problem we will not go into detail.

N.B.: **Casting should be done at float and not at int because it is not certain a priori that there are integers in the input string.**

---

#### Using List Comprehension

> [List comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) offers a shorter syntax when you want to create a
> new list based on the values of an existing list.

I divide the code into 3 steps just for greater understanding:

```py
input_string = "3,9,13,4,42"

num_list = [float(x) for x in input_string.split(",")]  # split list by comma and cast each element to float
squares_list = [x**2 for x in num_list]  # make square of each number in list
output_string = [str(x) for x in squares_list]  # cast to string each element in list

print(output_string)
```

---

#### Using join, map and lambda

> The [join() method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp) takes all items in an iterable and joins them into
> one string.
>
> The [map() function](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/map) applies a given function to each item of an
> iterable (list, tuple etc.) and returns an iterator.
>
> A Lambda Function is an anonymous function, that is, a function that
> has not been assigned a name and is used to use the features of
> functions but without having to define them.

```py
output_string = ','.join(map(lambda x: str(float(x)**2), input_string.split(',')))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right [assume-irrational-is-rational](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11622508/assume-irrational-is-rational)

```
string = "3,9,13,4,42"

def squares_string(string):
    output = ",".join(tuple(map(lambda x: str(int(x)**2), "3,9,13,4,42".split(","))))

    return output

output = squares_string(string)
print(output)
print(type(output))
```

Result:

```
9,81,169,16,1764
<class 'str'>
```